# select observations based on characters

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column in my dataset that R is interpreting as numeric when it should be character.  The original data was something like this: 1, 1.2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.2
It's really important for working with other datasets, that R doesn't add additional 0s, but when I import my csv file, the column looks like this: 1.0, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.2

How do I remove the extra 0s?  I was thinking something like this might work:

```
column <- c(1.0, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.2)
column <- if_else(column *contains* 0.2, column, round(column, 0)
```

But I'm not sure what function to use for *contains* (this is used to pick columns based on heading). Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to character as you mentioned it should ideally be one.

```
> column <- c(1.0, 1.2, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.2)
> class(column)
[1] "numeric"
> column <- as.character(column)
> class(column)
[1] "character"
> column
[1] "1"   "1.2" "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "5.2"
>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Who knew it would be so simple.